# Change User Agent client hints for Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, http-headers, user-agent

I've been changing the user agent with:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=" + USER_AGENT)
```

I've noticed that Chrome has additional user agent client hint headers such as `Sec-CH-UA-Platform`, `Sec-CH-UA` and more as seen and tested [here](https://user-agent-client-hints.glitch.me/).

I'd like to change these client hints (`Sec-CH-UA-Platform` in particular) without the use of an extension using Selenium. Is this possible similar to how the user agent can be changed?